# Как реализовать ход коня на краю шахматной доски

Tags: java, c++

Как реализовать ход коня на краю шахматной доски в массиве? У меня есть двух мерный массив 8х8 забит "0 1 0 1", нужно поставить коня на доске и отобразить все возможные позиции в следующий ход (их 8) с этим вопросов нету, но что делать если он стоит на краю доски? Он не может ходить в ту сторону где нету доски. Сделать всё через `if`, `else` или как?

Вот часть кода с `if`, `else`, но я посчитал что этот метод неочень и пошёл сюда

```
if (a[i][j] == 9) {
    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
        a[i+1][j+2] = 2; //2
        a[i+2][j+1] = 2;
    } else if (i == 0 && j == 1) {
        a[i+1][j+2] = 2;
        a[i+2][j+1] = 2;// 2 i 3.5
        a[i+1][j-2] = 2;
    } else {
        if (i == 0 && j >= 2) {
            a[i+1][j+2] = 2;  //  2
            a[i+2][j+1] = 2;  // sector
            a[i+1][j-2] = 2;  // 3
            a[i+2][j-1] = 2;  // sector
        }
        else if (i == 1 && j == 0)
```

Знаю что вопрос может быть тупой, но я еще учусь)

Comment: Чем в этом смысле уникален конь? Как реализовать ход слона на краю шахматной доски - Вам понятно?

Comment: К сожалению нет(

Answer (score 3):

Простите за мой <strike>французский</strike> C#:

```
bool IsValidCoords(int x, int y)
{
    return x >= 0 && x < 8 && y >= 0 && y < 8;
}

void ShowAllMovesOfKnight(int x, int y)
{
    int[,] knightSteps = { { -1, -2 }, { -1, 2 },
                           {  1, -2 }, {  1, 2 },
                           { -2, -1 }, { -2, 1 },
                           {  2, -1 }, {  2, 1 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        int newX = x + knightSteps[i, 0];
        int newY = y + knightSteps[i, 1];
        if (IsValidCoords(newX, newY))
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", newX, newY);
    }
}
```